# Как убрать результаты работы анимации при повторном запуске анимации?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

На примере ниже видно, что при первом запуске анимации все идет, как и ожидалось: анимация рисования линий с помощью изменения атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

В формуле анимации этого атрибута есть параметр `fill="freeze"`, который замораживает готовое изображение на дисплее после окончания анимации.
При повторном запуске анимации, часть изображения остается на экране.
Как удалить всё изображение с дисплея, перед началом повторной анимации.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_body.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<div><button id="btn1">Click me</button></div>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}
#mustache_1,#mustache_2,#mustache_3 {
stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="indefinite" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" >
      <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_body.end" values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
      <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
       <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
      <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>    
      
</svg>
```

Comment: Ходит молва, что новинки всяческие от лукавого и с трудом приживаются. Но, есть чудо-средство, что на жабескрипте настоено - грязным хаком зовётся ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грязный хак подсмотренный на [Хабре](https://qna.habr.com/q/797057#answer_1663109). "Хак" - потому, что решает проблему, а "грязный" из-за того, что убивает все прелести SMIL (всякие там begin.end и пр.), и нужно всё высчитывать и проставлять вручную. Ну, или писать ещё более продвинутую логику.

По сути, замена - это изъятие и последующая вставка. Вот, между этими событиями и очищается холст, а вставка идёт уже с изменённым атрибутом, поэтому анимация стартует сначала:

```js
let eye = document.getElementById("an_eye");
let mustache_1 = document.getElementById("an_mustache_1");
let mustache_2 = document.getElementById("an_mustache_2");
let mustache_3 = document.getElementById("an_mustache_3");

const btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  an_body.beginElement();
  eye = fRestartAnim(eye, 3600);
  mustache_1 = fRestartAnim(mustache_1, 5000);
  mustache_2 = fRestartAnim(mustache_2, 5000);
  mustache_3 = fRestartAnim(mustache_3, 5000);
});

function fRestartAnim(an, delay = 0) {
  const anClone = an.cloneNode(true);
  const anParent = an.parentNode;
  anParent.replaceChild(anClone, an);
  anClone.setAttribute("begin", performance.now() + delay + "ms");
  return anClone;
}
```

```html
<div><button id="btn1">Click me</button></div>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <style>
  .s0 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 5;
  }
  #mustache_1, #mustache_2, #mustache_3 {
    stroke-width: 3;
  }
  </style>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
    <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="indefinite" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>
  <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" >
    <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="indefinite" values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
    <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="indefinite" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
    <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="indefinite" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
    <animate id="an_mustache_3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="indefinite" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

В ответе **@UModeL** найдено хорошее решение. Очень часто, при создании анимаций, приходилось идти на всяческие ухищрения, чтобы замаскировать повторную прорисовку поверх уже оставшихся линий

> "Хак" - потому, что решает проблему, а "грязный" из-за того, что
> убивает все прелести SMIL (всякие там begin.end и пр.), и нужно всё
> высчитывать и проставлять вручную.

На мой взгляд, ничто не убивается и не нужно ничего высчитывать, если время начала очистки превышает время отработки анимации. За это время все логические цепочки отработают и их не нужно нигде хранить для повторного использования,  да и SVG не приспособлен для этого.   Потому что логические цепочки будут задействованы вновь при повторном запуске анимации.

Основная проблема в том, что крайние анимации, отработав своё. оставляют (замораживают) снимок результатов анимации. Делает это команда `fill="freeze"` Её можно убрать, но тогда анимацию будет видно только в процессе выполнения.

Я сделал небольшое исследование, чтобы понять отчего и при каких условиях остаются следы прошлых анимаций.

***#1.*** Если анимация одна, то при повторном запуске анимации следов не остается

```html
<div><button id="btn1">Click me</button></div>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1.5s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
       
</svg>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_body.beginElement();
})
</script>
```

***#2.***  Можно зациклить эту анимацию с некоторой паузой (1s) между повторениями, результат будет тот же

`begin="svg1.click;an_body.end+1s"`

```html
<div><button id="btn1">Click me</button></div>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1.5s" begin="svg1.click;an_body.end+1s" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
       
</svg>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_body.beginElement();
})
</script>
```

***#3.*** Несколько анимаций запускаются одновременно по клику на холсте SVG `begin="svg1.click"` и имеют одинаковое время продолжительности.  `dur="4s"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}
#mustache_1,#mustache_2,#mustache_3 {
stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" >
      <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
      <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
       <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
      <animate id="an_mustache_3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>    
      
</svg>
```

***#4.*** Несколько анимаций стартуют одновременно `begin="svg1.click"`, но разная продолжительность анимаций: `dur= "4s"`, `3s`, `2s`, `1s`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}
#mustache_1,#mustache_2,#mustache_3 {
stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" >
      <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
      <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
       <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="3s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
      <animate id="an_mustache_3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>    
      
</svg>
```

### Промежуточный вывод

Следов работы анимаций SVG не будет видно, если при повторном запуске:

1. Запуск всех анимаций, входящих в одно приложение SVG произведен одновременно
2. Продолжительность входящих анимаций не влияет на результат.

***5#.*** Разное время запуска анимаций. Запуск с задержкой, относительно первой анимации

`begin="svg1.click+2s"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}
#mustache_1,#mustache_2,#mustache_3 {
stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" >
      <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click+3s" values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  
  </path>
  <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
      <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" begin="svg1.click" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
       <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="3s" begin="svg1.click+1s" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
      <animate id="an_mustache_3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" begin="svg1.click+2s" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>    
      
</svg>
```

Из работы приложения видно, что анимации прорисовки усов и глаза животного начинались с задержкой относительно анимации тела.
При повторном запуске всего SVG на холсте остались следы именно тех анимаций, которые запускались с задержкой.

### Окончательный вывод

Наличие или отсутствие следов прошедших анимаций при повторном запуске и `fill="freeze"`, зависит исключительно от времени запуска анимаций:

1. **Нет следов** при одновременном запуске, несмотря на разную продолжительность анимаций
2. Остатки прошедших анимаций появляются, - при разном времени запуска анимаций

---

В некоторых случаях можно воспользоваться параметром **restart="never"**, который позволит отработать всем анимациям, но запретит повторный запуск. Естественно никаких следов не будет, так как нужно будет перегрузить документ, что приведет к очистке.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<style>
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:5;
}
#mustache_1,#mustache_2,#mustache_3 {
stroke-width:3;
}

</style>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#D6DFE6" />
  <path id="body" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 2482" d="m228.8 142c0 0-1 9.2 1.5 12.7 6.9 9.7 20.4 13.6 32.2 15.7 13.1 2.3 27.1 0.1 39.7-4.1 13.2-4.4 24.9-12.8 36-21.3 5.6-4.3 10.6-9.5 15-15 4.6-5.8 9.8-11.6 12-18.7 2.2-7 3.3-14.4 0.7-22.1C360.6 72.7 351.5 65 340.9 56.1 326.1 43.9 308.2 34.5 289.5 30.3c-19.5-4.4-40.4-2.6-59.9 1.5-20.1 4.2-39.6 12.3-56.9 23.2-24.2 15.3-46.2 35-63.7 57.7-18.9 24.5-34 52.7-42.7 82.4-7.7 26.3-10.4 54.7-7.5 82 4.4 41.8 18.8 62.2 37.5 88.1 11.1 15.3 27 26.8 42.7 37.5 13.2 9 27.5 16.8 42.7 21.7 13.5 4.4 27.8 5.4 41.9 6.7 27 2.5 81.3 2.2 81.3 2.2l74.9-0.7c0 0 33.9-0.2 49.4-1 9.3-0.5 13-14.3 15.7-23.2 2.8-9.1 2.3-19.3 0-28.5-2.7-11-8.6-21.2-15.7-30-6.3-7.8-14.8-13.8-23.2-19.3-12.1-7.8-25.1-14.7-39-18.9-12.5-3.8-25.9-5.4-39-5.2-17.9 0.2-35.9 3.4-53.2 8.2-4.7 1.3-13.4 5.5-13.4 5.5 0 0 13.4-17.7 21.2-25.6 9.3-9.4 19.6-18 30.4-25.7 13-9.1 26.8-17.3 41.2-23.9 13.8-6.3 27.9-12.8 42.9-15 18.2-2.7 37.5-2.3 55.2 2.6 14.2 3.9 27.1 12.3 39 21 10.4 7.6 18.8 17.6 27.7 27 7.9 8.3 13.3 24.3 10.5 36.7-2.1 9.1-10.1 17.4-18.7 21-9 3.8-21.6 4.6-29.2-1.5-8.2-6.7-9.4-20.2-8.2-30.7 1.4-12.3 8.8-23.9 17.2-33 8.4-9 19.4-16.7 31.5-19.5 11.7-2.7 25.2-1.6 36 3.7 8.9 4.4 15.6 13 20.2 21.7 4.6 8.6 6.8 19.4 6.7 28.5 0 9.5-16.5 23.2-16.5 23.2 0 0 19.8 2.8 29.2 6 9.7 3.3 19.2 7.6 27.5 13.5 9.6 6.9 17.6 15.9 24.9 25.2 4.7 5.9 11.9 19 11.9 19l9 18c0 0 0.7 15.9 6.7 18.7 3.9 1.8 11.1-0.3 12-4.5 0.4-1.7-2.1-3-3.7-3.7-2.3-1.1-5.1-1.6-7.5-0.7-3.3 1.2-7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5h-26.2l-43.9 0.9c0 0-14.8-0.4-22.2-0.4-13.2-0.1-26.6-0.3-39.7 0.2-16.9 0.6-34.3-0.6-53.8 0.1-15.7 0.5-51.6 0.5-51.6 0.5" >
      <animate id="an_body" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1.5s" begin="svg1.click" values="0 2482;2482 0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
  
  </path>
   <path id="eye" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 43" d="m570.4 371.6c0 0 5.3-5.3 8.5-7.2 2.9-1.7 6.1-3.4 9.5-3.7 3.6-0.3 7.5 0.5 10.7 2.3 3.1 1.7 7.4 7.5 7.4 7.5" > 
       <set attributeName="restart" to="never" calcMode="discrete" begin="an_body.begin" /> 
       <animate id="an_eye" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="0.8s" begin="svg1.click+1s"
         values="0 43;43 0" fill="freeze" restart="never" /> 
</path>    
  
 <path id="mustache_1" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 110" d="m542.9 462c2.5-8 7-15.1 10.7-22.5 2.5-4.9 5.2-9.7 7.7-14.7 1.2-2.5 2.2-5.1 3.6-7.5 0.6-1.1 1.1-2.1 2-3.2 0.2-0.3 0.5 0.6 0.4 0.9-1 4.9-2.3 8.2-3.8 12.2-1.3 3.4-3.1 6.6-4.8 9.8-1.2 2.3-2.4 4.6-3.6 6.9-1.1 2-2.2 4.1-3.3 6.1-2.2 4-4.6 9-6.8 11.8-1.9 2.4-2.3 0.9-2.1 0.3z" >
      <animate id="an_mustache_1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 110;110 0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_2" class="s0" stroke-dasharray="0 157" d="m589.1 412.5c-1 3.9-0.4 9.7-1.1 14.6-0.8 5.5-2.3 10.9-3.4 16.4-1.2 6-2.7 11.9-3.7 17.9-1.1 6.4-2.4 12.8-2.6 19.3-0.1 1.9-0.3 7.3 0.3 5.6 1.5-5 1.7-7.7 2.6-11.6 1.3-5.6 2.9-11.1 4.3-16.6 1.3-5.2 2.6-10.3 3.5-15.5 0.5-2.8 0.9-5.6 1.2-8.3 0.4-3.7 0.9-7.3 1.1-11 0.2-3.7-0.2-7.1-0.1-11.3 0.1-3.8-1.5-1.6-2 0.5z" >
       <animate id="an_mustache_2" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 157;157 0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
  </path>      
  <path id="mustache_3" stroke-dasharray="0 159" class="s0" d="m608.2 408.4c-0.2 4.1 0.6 6.9 1.3 10.3 0.5 2.4 1.4 4.7 2 7 1.3 5.6 1.8 11.4 3.2 16.9 1.5 6.2 3.7 12.2 5.6 18.3 2.4 7.7 4.1 15.7 7.4 22.9 0.2 0.4 1.3 0.3 1.3-0.1-0.3-5.6-1.2-6.9-1.9-10.3-1.2-6.1-2.3-12.3-3.7-18.4-0.9-4-2-7.9-3.2-11.8-0.9-2.9-2-5.6-2.9-8.5-1-3.1-2.1-6.2-3-9.4-1.6-5.4-2.3-9.6-4.5-16.2-0.2-0.6-1.6-1.4-1.6-0.8z">
      <animate id="an_mustache_3" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" begin="an_eye.end" 
        values="0 159;159 0" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
  </path>    
      
</svg>
```